# Trace32 stopped once adding coverage buffer to coverage database

Tags: trace32

Refer to PRACTICE Script Language Reference of Trace32 tool:

https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/general_ref_c.pdf

```
Analyzer.Mode Stack
Go sieve
…
COVerage.ADD
; clear trace buffer and use stack mode
; run a part of the application
; process the trace buffer
```

After "Coverage.ADD" command for adding coverage buffer to coverage database, Trace32 will stop its execution and require a manual action of users.
"Stop" meant that Trace32 would break at the next CMM statement and users have to click "Continue" button to go.
[image]

How to set up Trace32 not stop after "Coverage.ADD" command and execution next statement (*.cmm script)

Comment: What do you mean with "Trace32 will stop its execution"? (Does the target CPU halt? Is a dialog popping up? Does the trace recording stop? Does the TRACE32 application crash?) Which user action allows to continue?

Comment: "Stop" meant that Trace32 would break at the next CMM statement (cmm script) and users have to click "Continue" button to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRACTICE Script Language provides **ON < EVENT >** to catch events raising during script execution.

https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/practice_ref.pdf
[image]

Thus, the below command is very useful in this case.

**GLOBALON ERROR CONTINUE // Suppress PBREAK**